# Yesod: i18n of custom form fields error messages

Tags: forms, haskell, internationalization, message, yesod

I use `checkBool` helper to build custom form fields, e.g.:

```
posDoubleField :: forall msg (m :: * -> *).
    ( RenderMessage (HandlerSite m) FormMessage
    , RenderMessage (HandlerSite m) msg, Monad m )
               => msg -> Field m Double
posDoubleField msg = checkBool (> 0) msg doubleField

-- ...
mkDepForm :: Form FormDepositHelper
mkDepForm = renderDivs $ FormDepositHelper
            <$> areq (posDoubleField errMsg) (fieldSettingsLabel MsgDepositAmount) (Just 0)
    where
       errMsg :: Text
       errMsg = "Invalid deposit amount!"
```

As you can see, I have internationalised field label, so can I use internationalised error message too? Or have I to build whole field myself following the [source code example](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-form-1.3.15/docs/src/Yesod-Form-Fields.html)?

Comment: Does it not work to simply use an i18n value in place of `errMsg`? All of the types seem to line up nicely for that.

Comment: Great! This works, but I don't understand why, to be more precise how it works.

Comment: I'm on a mobile right now so can't answer at length. Look at the definition of the RenderMessage typeclass, which provides the heart of i18n in yesod. There's also a chapter in the book about it.

Comment: I still "floating" in Haskell world, so unfortunately I read much more that I understand :( Actually I always reread Yesod book and other  known examples before ask something. Thank you a lot, you're very pleasant! I need achieve deep insight of Haskell itself, especially monad transformers, because as I understood Yesod is generally build with monad transformers.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman, can you post an answer so I can mark question as answered, or if you're too busy, I can do it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting comment from above:

Does it not work to simply use an i18n value in place of `errMsg`? All of the types seem to line up nicely for that.